# Кто создатель кодировки base64

Tags: кодировка, base64, история

Кто автор(создатель) кодировки Base64?

Comment: Самое раннее упоминание нашёл в RFC 989, дальше уже видимо в интернет-археологию закапываться надо

Comment: @andreymal объявим John Linn автором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 был разработан Инженерным советом Интернета (англ. Internet Engineering Task Force, IETF). Впервые этот стандарт кодирования был описан в 1987 в RFC 989, а свое название получил в 1992.

Автор RFC 989 - John Linn.

Подробнее об IETF: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0

Подробнее о base64 в RFC 989 (см. параграф 4.3): https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc989

Comment: https://base64.guru/learn/what-is-base64 тут тоже вспоминают эту историю

Comment: Пересмотрел ваши ссылки но так и не нашел того человека, странно что про него ни где нет информации.

Comment: Это не один человек разработал, работала группа инженеров, но имен их найти не удалось.

Comment: да группа группой но всегда есть один человек который дал идею, от как раз его я и ищу

Comment: Желаю успеха, она вам понадобится)

Comment: ах да, забыл кое что, есть уточнение что он популярен среди ux дизайнеров и front end разработчиков.

Comment: @ВиталийПинчук Нашел, это John Linn. Его имя указано в шапке RFC 989. Также нашел ссылку на него в литературе (см сноску 88): https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=X9MYlT-Fk2gC&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=john+linn+ietf+1987&source=bl&ots=UJTKE_Z0b2&sig=ACfU3U29ZU95O7FulJ6ucUjqVEwg6C8XRw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo-PCttuPoAhUniYsKHXc-CcsQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=john%20linn%20ietf%201987&f=false

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106643/discussion-between---and-yuri-pokhylko).

Comment: спасибо вроде John Linn. правда он под условия "популярен среди ux дизайнеров и front end разработчиков" не попадает)